# jQuery splice inArray with multiple key objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

Javascript newbie here --

I have the following array:

```
var group = ({ 
        one: value1,
        two: value2,
        three: value3
    });
```

I want to check if array "group" is part of "groupsArray" and add it if doesn't or remove it if it does.

```
var groupLocate = $.inArray(group, groupsArray);
if(groupLocate ==-1){
        groupsArray.push(group);
        } else {
        groupsArray.splice($.inArray(group, groupsArray),1);
        }
```

This method works with single value arrays. Unfortunately, I can't get it to work in this case with three keys and values as groupLocate always returns -1.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: That's no array -- that's an object!

Comment: That is not an array.

Comment: oops. well that explains it... thanks.

Comment: Can you show the code for groupsArray?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First it helps to understand why `$.inArray()` didn't work. Let's try a simpler case. Paste this in to the JavaScript console in your browser on a page with jQuery loaded (such as this page we're on) and run it:

```
var object = { a: 1 };
var array = [ { a: 1 } ];
console.log( '$.inArray: ', $.inArray( object, array ) );
```

(Note the terminology: your `group` variable is an Object, not an Array.)

Now it looks like `object` is in the array, right? Why does it print `-1` then? Try this:

```
console.log( object );
console.log( array[0] );
```

They look the same. How about:

```
console.log( '== or === works? ', object == array[0], object === array[0] );
```

Or even simpler:

```
console.log( 'Does {a:1} == {a:1}? ', {a:1} == {a:1} );
console.log( 'What about {} == {}? ', {} == {} );
```

Those all print `false`!

This is because two objects that happen to have the same content are still two separate objects, and when you use `==` or `===` to compare two objects, you are actually testing whether they are both references to one and the same object. Two different objects will never compare equal, even if they contain exactly the same content.

`$.inArray()` works like using an `===` operator to compare two objects - it won't find an object in an array unless it is *the same object*, not just an object with identical content.

Knowing this, does that suggest any possible ways to approach the problem? There are several ways you could write your own code to search the array for your object, or you may find it helpful to use a library such as [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) which has many useful methods for arrays and objects.

For example, you could use [`_.findWhere( groupsArray, group )`](http://underscorejs.org/#findWhere) to find the first match - with the caveat that it only compares the properties that are in the `group` object. For example, if `group` is `{a:1}`, it would match an object in the `groupsArray` array that was `{a:1,b:2}`.

If you need an exact match, you could combine Underscore's [`_.find()`](http://underscorejs.org/#find) and [`_.isEqual()`](http://underscorejs.org/#isEqual) methods:

```
var index = _.find( groupsArray, function( element ) {
    return  _.isEqual( element, group );
});
```

Now one last thing to watch out for. Your code that pushes the `group` object onto the `groupsArray` array - you know that pushes the actual `group` object itself. It doesn't make a copy of it in the array, it's a reference to the very same object. (Ironically, this means that your original code to find `group` in the array would actually work in the case where you'd pushed that same `group` object onto the array yourself.)

If you want to make sure the elements in `groupsArray` are each their own independent object, and not a reference to another object floating around in your code, you can use another Underscore method to do a shallow copy:

```
groupsArray.push( _.clone(group) );
```

If `group` has any nested objects, though, this won't copy them. (I don't see a deep copy function in Underscore, although you could write one if you need it.)

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks for taking the time to explain this.

Comment: My pleasure! Sometimes I worry that I'm too longwinded with these kinds of explanations, so I'm glad it was useful. :-)